# TypeScript: Getting Value from an Enum Key in Interface

Tags: typescript, enums

I created an enum named `FoodTypes`:

```
enum FoodTypes {
    Meat,
    Veggie,
}
```

Then I declared an interface named `Recipe` that contains arrays of objects of `FoodTypes`.

```
interface Recipe {
    [FoodTypes.Meat]: [
        { name: 'Beef', val: 120 },
        { name: 'Pork', val: 200 },
    ],
    [FoodTypes.Veggie]: [
        { name: 'Mushroom', val: 30 },
        { name: 'Lettuce', val: 10 },
    ],
};
```

How do I access a specific value in the interface?
For example, I'd like to get the `val` of `Beef`.
`// should be 120`

Thanks so much!

Edit:
@captain-yossarian For example, if I want to pass in the value later in a function as it changes dynamically (using React Redux in front-end), would I be able to do so?
I know that the following wouldn't work since I'm referring to a type:

```
function getBeefVal(recipe: Recipe) {
return "Beef Val: " + Recipe[FoodTypes.Meat][0]['val'];
}
```

Comment: That interface is exceedingly suspicious. Are you absolutely certain you intended to declare a *type* which requires `FoodTypes.Meat`'s two properties to have specific literal values? It seems like you just want a runtime lookup table, not a type-level interface.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @SilvioMayolo! The full breakdown of the interfaces is technically:  `interface IFoodAttribute {name: string; value: number }` & `interface IFood { [FoodTypes.Meat]: IFoodAttribute[] }`. The specific literal values will be passed in dynamically in Redux. If there's a better way to do things, please let me know as I'm quite new to TS. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
type Beef = Recipe[FoodTypes.Meat][0]['val'] // 120
```

You can use the square bracket notation to get a nested property of an interface. Just like plain JS.

> if I want to pass in the value later in a function as it changes dynamically (using React Redux in front-end), would I be able to do so? I know that the following wouldn't work since I'm referring to a type:

TS has two scopes. One for types, let's name it `TypeScope` - another one for values - `ValueScope`

It is impossible to use types from `TypeScope` in the `ValueScope`. Because all types are removed after the compilation.

In some cases it is possible to use values from `ValueScope` in `TypeScope`. For example `classes`.

```js
class A {
    age: number = 0
}

const x: A = { age: 42 } // ok
```

In above example I have used `A` class from `ValueScope` as a type in `TypeScope`.

Comment: @blackgreen fair enough, I made an update

Comment: Thank you @captain-yossarian & @blackgreen! This may be a silly question but is there a way to access this as a value instead of type?

Comment: @supvicky I'm not sure what do U mean. Could you please update the question with example?

Comment: @captain-yossarian Thanks for your reply! Done! Hopefully, it makes more sense :')